# Prove that $\limsup_{n\to\infty} |X_n|/n \le1 $ almost surely

Tags: probability, random-variable

Suppose {$X_n$} a sequence of random variables.
If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(|X_n|>n)<{\infty}$

Prove that $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{ |X_n|}{n} \le1 $$ almost surely

**What i have done so far:**

I thought using the Borel-Cantelli lemma could lead me somewhere, but i didn't have any luck.

From Borel-Cantelli lemma we know that if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(|X_n|>n)<{\infty}$ then $P(|X_n|>n)=0$

How could I proceed?

Comment: Perhaps you can tell us what problem you encountered applying Borel-Cantelli. (Hint: There is none.)

Comment: @cardinal I added to my question above my approach, but my problem is how we pass from the probability to limsup

Comment: First, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb P(|X_n| > n) < \infty$ imples $\mathbb P(|X_n| > n \,\mathrm{i.o.}) = 0$. The "infinitely often" ($\mathrm{i.o.}$) part is *very* important. This now comes down to understanding the definitions of (i) "infinitely often", (ii) "almost surely" and (iii) $\limsup$.

Comment: Crosspost: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/438118/7003

Comment: This question was cross-posted on the Math site and has been answered there.

Comment: Defining $A_n=\{|X_n|>n\}$, we have $P(\limsup\{|X_n|/n\leq 1\})=P(\limsup A_n^c)=1-P(\liminf A_n)=1$, because $\liminf A_n\subset\limsup A_n$ and $P(\limsup A_n)=0$ by Borel-Cantelli.

Comment: @Zen $P(\limsup\{|X_n|/n \le 1\}) \to P(\{\limsup|X_n|/n \le 1\})$ ?